# Python 3.7 guess the number program not looping back to options input when option one is finished

Tags: python-3.x

When option one finishes and you have guessed the right number, the program is breaking out of all loops, printing exit program and exiting. I need it to loop back to the options input, option=int(input("Choose an option 1 -3 ")). Option 2 loops back to options input fine. I can't see anything different in the code to tell me why this is happening.

I have been online with 2 tutors who did nothing but break my code into uselessness. I am new to coding so my code may be sloppy or not what people are used to seeing.

I get no error messages, the code works except for option 1 not looping back to options input. When option 1 finishes it ends the program instead of looping back to option=int(input("Choose an option 1 - 3 "))

```
#display welcome message
print("Welcome to the guess my number program")
import random

#start outside while loop for options
while True:
    print("1 You guess the number ")
    print("2 You enter a number and see if the computer can guess it ")
    print("3 Exit Program ")
    #get option input from user
    #inside if loop and set random integer
    option = int(input("Choose an option 1 - 3 "))
    #option 1
    if(option == 1):
        myNumber = random.randint(1, 10)
        #set count
        count = 1
        #inside while loop
    while True:
        try:
            print("Guess a number between 1 and 10 ")
            #get guess
            guess=int(input("Guess a number"))
            #inside while loop
            while guess<1 or guess>10:
                print("Invalid entry, please choose a number between 1 and 10 ")
                #get guess
                guess=int(input("guess a number "))
        except:
            print("Please enter numbers only ")
            continue
    #display guess result to user, tally guess count
        if guess < myNumber:
            print("Your guess is to low, guess again")
            count = count + 1
        elif guess > myNumber:
            print("Your guess is to high, guess again")
            count = count + 1
        elif guess == myNumber:
            print("Great job, you guessed it in " 
                  + str(count) + " attempts \n")
            break

    #option 2
    if (option == 2):
        count = 1
        #get number input from user
         number = int(input("Choose a number for the computer to try to guess "))
         while True:
            #get random value from computer
            computerGuess = random.randint(1, 10)
            #inside if loop, display guess to user, tally guess count

            if(computerGuess < number):
                print("Computer guess is to low")
                count = count + 1
            elif(computerGuess > number  ):
                print("Computer guess is to high")
                count = count + 1
            elif(computerGuess == number):
                print("The computer has guessed the right number in " 
                  + str(count) + " attempts. The number was " + str(number) )
                break
    else:
        print("You are exiting the program")
        break
```

Comment: If your intention is to stay in the program unless someone types a different number than 1 or 2 as option, then 1> Your indentation of If statement for option 2 should be at similar level as option 1., 2> Option2 clause should be an elif , rathar than a separate if condition, 3> Last else block (which exits the outer loop) should also be within the outer While Loop

Comment: Thank you for the input, san. Changing the if clause on option 2 to elif fixed the code it is working now!!!

Comment: glad that it helped. :-) Could you please accept the answer in such case and vote it? I have just posted the above comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to stay in the program unless someone types a different number than 1 or 2 as option, then

1. Your indentation of 'if' statement for option 2 should be at similar level as option 1.
2. Option2 clause should be an 'elif', rather than a separate 'if' condition.
3. Last 'else' block (which exits the outer loop) should also be within the outer While Loop